# can't run method from subclass of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to run a game inside a subclass "gameArea" of JLabel using "gameArea.runGame();", but I get the error "cannot resolve method 'runGame'. I know I could run all of this outside of the subclass "gameArea", but understanding why I can't do it this way would be helpful. I've stripped out all the unnecessary code.

```
package Components;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private BottomPanel bottomPanel;
    private JLabel gameArea;

    public MainFrame() {

        super("test window");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();
        gameArea = new GameArea();

        add(gameArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);


        bottomPanel.startBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameArea.runGame(); // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
            }
        });
        setSize(800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);


    }



}
```

```
package Components;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameArea extends JLabel {


    public GameArea() {

        setText("Waiting for Input");

    }

    public void runGame() {

        setText("Game has been run");

    }

}
```

```
package Components;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

    public JButton startBTN;

    public BottomPanel() {

        startBTN = new JButton("Start");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        add(startBTN);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private JLabel gameArea;
```

A JLabel does NOT have a method runGame().

Your code should be:

```
private GameArea gameArea;
```

Then you will be able to use `gameArea.runGame()`.

But the real question is why are you even doing this?

You can just invoke `setText(...)` on the label to change the text. There is no need to create a custom class with a custom method.

Comment: I used setText(...) just to show the problem. the actual program has something more complicated there.

Comment: In any case you have received the answer to your question. So don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the type of `gameArea` as `JLabel`. The `JLabel` interface doesn't have a method `runGame`. You will need to cast `gameArea` to be able to call the method

```
((GameArea) gameArea).runGame()
```